# Input mask through directive

Tags: regex, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I want an input to follow the following format:

```
[00-23]:[00-59]
```

We use angular 2.4 so we don't have the `pattern` directive available and I cannot use external libraries (primeNG).

So I'm trying to make a directive for that:

```
@HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) onKeyUp(event) {
    var newVal = this.el.nativeElement.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    var rawValue = newVal;
    // show default format for empty value
    if(newVal.length === 0) {
        newVal = '00:00';
    } 
    // don't show colon for empty groups at the end
    else if(newVal.length === 1) {
        newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{1})/, '00:0$1');
    } else {
        newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1:$2');
    }
    // set the new value
    this.el.nativeElement.value = newVal;
}
```

This works for the first 2 digits I enter.

Starting string:

```
00:00
```

Pressing numpad 1:

```
00:01
```

pressing numpad 2:

```
00:12
```

But on the third digit I get:

```
00:123
```

Instead of `01:23` and `00:1234` instead of `12:34`

Backspace works as expected.

Is there a solution to this problem using only a directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last rejex try `replace(/^(\d{0,2})(\d{0,2})/g, '$1:$2')`. Hope this will help.